# Allow Hyphens and apostraphes but no other special characters

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I have the following validation expresion on an asp.net web form that allows alphanumeric characters, spaces,at least one alpha character, and a minimum of 3 characters and a maximum of 20:
ValidationExpression="(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9 _]{3,20})$"

Now I have been asked to allow hyphens and apostraphes but no other special characters.

How can I implement this in my current validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `(?!^[0-9'-]$)(?!^[a-zA-Z'-]$)^([a-zA-Z0-9 _'-]{3,20})$`?

Well, the main trick here is that `-` sign should be placed at the end of the character group for it to be parsed as a literal hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?=.*?[A-Za-z]+)^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-' ]{3,20}$
```